# How to implement a class with inner implementation dependent on template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to write a class such that it's inner implementation depends on the template parameters. For instance (and I dont know if this is possible), say I could write something like:

```
MyClass<double,1> a;
```

and then this would be expanded at compile time as:

```
class MyClass{
double d;
public:
  MyClass(){d=0;}
};
```

and if instead I instantiated it as:

```
MyClass<double,2> a;
```

it would expand to:

```
class MyClass{
double d[3];
public:
  MyClass(){for(int i=0;i<3;i++) d[i]=0;}
};
```

Is this somehow possible using templates?
Please note that I dont want to have a double* d since I want to everything be static.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with partial specialization:

```
// base template must be defined first
template <class T, std::size_t N>
class MyClass {
    T d[N+1];
public:
    MyClass() { for (std::size_t i=0; i<N+1; i++) d[i] = 0; }
};

// then the partial specialization for N = 1:
template <class T>
class MyClass<T, 1> {
    T d;
public:
    MyClass() { d = 0; }
};
```

I'm a little uncertain about the base version--you show it as expanding to three items in the array when instantiated with the value `2`, so that's what I've done above. I'd *expect* that to be the result from instantiating with the value `3` instead though. If that's what you really want, change both the `N+1`s to `N`.

Also note that at least for the specialized version, you'd normally want to use initialization instead of assignment, so the ctor would be more like:

```
MyClass() : d(0) {}
```

or (preferably):

```
MyClass() : d(T()) {}
```

You might also want to include a specialization for `N=0` that wouldn't compile (or, about equivalently, use `static_assert` in the base template to assure that N>1).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know partial specialization actually meant providing a whole new structure/functionality. I thought (clearly erroneously) that by partially specializing I was adding  more stuff to the class (like with inheritance). I tried your example and I used sizeof to get the class size and to my surprise sizeof(Myclass<double,2>)=24 and sizeof(MyClass<double>)=8!!!. This is what I wanted, thank you!!